# Relation between repeat number in coin toss

Tags: statistics

I am trying to establish correlation between tossing of coins and occurring of repeats.

> Coin is flipped 10 time as follows:
>
> $${\rm H.T.H.H.H.T.H.T.T.T. }$$
>
> After each repeat occurring I have put (R) as follows:
>
> $$ {\rm H.T.H.H(R).H(R).T.H.T.T(R).T(R). }  $$

So in this exercise I have 4 repeats,  any patteren/symmetry/correlation could be estblised here?

Is it fair to conclude in 10 toss I get  4 repeats and establish for 12th or 13th flip repeat is certain?

(Stats novice)

Comment: I made an edit to enhance readability. Please make sure I did *not* change the question semantics.

Comment: *Certainty* is not achievable. It is possible, though highly unlikely, that the first $50$ tosses will monotonously alternate between H and T. But information about the distribution of the number of repeats is obtainable, and information about the *mean* number of repeats in say $10$ tosses (or $n$ tosses)  tosses is easy to get.  The mean number of repeats in $10$ tosses is $4.5$.

Comment: Thanks Andre,  I have tried in Excel using random command for 2000 flips. The R was 969, Heads were 984 and Tails were 1016. Now is is possible to get clear picture?Thanks in advance Rodney

Answer (score 1):

We assume the coin is fair. Then after the first toss, the probability of a repeat is $1/2$. For $k>1$, the event there is an R at position $k$ is independent of previous locations of the R's. So if we toss the coin $n$ times, the number of R's has *binomial* distribution, where the number of trials is $n-1$, and the probability of success each time is $1/2$. Thus if $X$ is the total number of R's, then
$$P(X=m)=\binom{n}{m}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}.$$